# Jmeter - Getting previous results in mail

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I'm using Jmeter - it runs automatically every 4 hours (through crontab). I'm sending the results file (csv) in the mail at the end of the test. I always see the file of the **previous** test, not the current one (I can see by the hour).

the structure is this: one 'Test Plan' (I **checked** 'Run Thread Groups consecutively' **and** 'Run tearDown Thread Groups after shutdown of main threads), two 'Thread Groups' - which at the end of each I write results to csv file using 'View Results Tree', and at the end - 'TearDown Thread Group' that uses SMTP sampler to send the files created.

[image: Test Plan structure]

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the SMTP sampler settings:
[image: SMTP Sampler - part1]

[image: SMTP Sampler - part2]

and this is the writing to the file:
[image: Writing to the file]

Comment: can you show your smtp sampler config ? and also expand each thread group and show where you create csv if you do ?

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to Autoflush policy which flushes content of buffer only when buffer is reached.
As you use a tear down thread group results are nit guaranteed to be fully written as test is not really finished.
The fact that you think you are sending previous test file might be due to jmeter appending data to the same results file.

So :

1/ ensure you move or delete the file once sent

2/ Edit user.properties and add:

> jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
>   This will make jmeter write to file any sample result immediately afte it is executed.

Comment: seems like the 'jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true' did the work. and BTW it's 'jmeter.properties' and not 'user.properties'. what is the cost of using that parameter as true? why isn't it the default? Thanks.

Comment: Hi user.properties overrides jmeter.properties, it's best practices to put in user.properties. It's not the default due to performance impact, your need is specific. If answer is ok you should accept it and upvote

Comment: it actually didn't work with user.properties for some reason, but only with jmeter.properties.

Comment: i will check but it would be a bug. You should accept answer