# How to email the updated test result in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a simple HTTP Request sampler in a test plan. And, viewing the result through "Aggregate Report" and writing the same results to a file.  I have used "SMTP Sampler" in "tearDown Thread Group" and also used the "Test Action" to wait for a while. 
Issue is, once I execute the test-case, in mail I got the previous run results instead of the new one.

Here is the screen-shot of my test plan.[image]

**Please help. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you share more details / sreenshot of your SMTP sampler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter - Getting previous results in mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352502/jmeter-getting-previous-results-in-mail)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your "Test Action to wait for a while" approach as it may be not enough so you won't be able to tell for sure whether JMeter stored the most recent results or not.

I would suggest the following: add `jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true` line to *user.properties* file (it's located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) and on next JMeter start it will be storing every single line.

So

1. Apply aforementioned property change
2. Configure your SMTP Sampler to send `results.jtl` file
3. Disable all the listeners.
4. [Run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as follows

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
   ```
5. As an alternative to editing *user.properties* file you can pass the property via -J command line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them.