# jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin from the Jenkins always analysis the old .jtl file and generates HTML report

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

[image]

When I execute the JMeter test f either from command prompt or Eclipse via mvn  jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin picks the right .jtl report , but where as when i ran from jenkins  jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin picking the old .jtl file.

I have attached my pom file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look a this. It may solve your problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250273/how-to-email-the-updated-test-result-in-jmeter

Comment: Hi Arif,  NO luck even though after I set jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true it's still picking the old .jtl file.I have updated the original post by adding the Jenkins error screenshot